# Сделать div адаптивным

Tags: html, css

у меня есть тако div

```
 <div class="rektitles" style="background:#cfebfe; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; color:#5e7f96; text-align: center;  word-wrap: break-word;">Подайте заявку в несколько компаний, чтобы увеличить шанс одобрения до 100%</div>
```

Когда захожу с ПК, отлично отображается, с телефона тоже , только есть проблема, весь текст не видно, а видно только "Подайте заявку в несколько компаний, чтобы ", подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать его адаптивным?

Comment: в index.html у вас указан viewport?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: добавьте перенос текста

Comment: вы делаете верстку шаблона письма?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте **min-height** вместо **height**.

```css
.rektitles {
    background: #cfebfe;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #5e7f96;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="rektitles" style="">Подайте заявку в несколько компаний, чтобы увеличить шанс одобрения до 100%</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

добавь `display: block;` к классу `rektitles`

Comment: Вы серьезно? 
Назовите Джонни Деппа -  Джонни Деппом

Comment: На то всему сущему и даются имена..

Comment: он это сказал к тому, что у `div`, блочного элемента, `display: block;` по умолчанию